# Executing batch file does not retrieve information and save it in a .txt

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

So I tried to get the information of newly registered users in a textfile.

I came to this script:

```
$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-0)).Date 
Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated > C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\newuserinfo.txt
```

if I execute this in powershell it works but if I try to execute this from a .bat file the .txt file is empty with no information about the user.

Has this to do with the "$When" variable?

Comment: Oh btw I need to first execute this command: $When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-0)).Date   and then this one: Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated > C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\newuserinfo.txt

Comment: I feel the need to point out the obvious problem and state that a batch script won't run that exact code you posted because batch isn't PowerShell.

Comment: oh ok. i'm pretty new to this tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trail to create a .bat file with the following content:

```
Powershell.exe -command "$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-15)).Date;Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties whenCreated  | Export-Csv d:\temp\u.csv"
```